# Как рассчитать углы наклона луча между двумя точками в пространстве?

Tags: геометрия, вектор

У меня есть точка в 3D пространстве, есть её координаты и есть луч (его координаты и угол его наклона по осям x и y), мне нужно чтобы он указывал в точку, но точка постоянно меняет свое местоположение и мне нужно рассчитывать угол наклона вектора в реальном времени.

Comment: Вам все-все объяснить надо, или вы все-таки можете указать что именно неясно?

Comment: `но моих знаний не достаточно` - расскажите, для чего их достаточно, что вы уже поняли, а с чем конкретно возникли затруднения. Иначе  в ответе придётся написать книгу и в ней объяснить всё, включая арифметику и базовый синтаксис C++.

Comment: Моя проблема такова, этот код рассчитывает расстояние от луча  до точки в пространстве и записывает его в result, все работает верно, но мне нужно получить отдельно расстояние по осям x и y,  но я уже просто не могу понять как их вычислить. Если поможете - буду очень благодарен!

Comment: Сформулирую мою задачу: у меня есть точка в 3D пространстве, есть её координаты и есть луч(его координаты и угол его наклона по осям x и y), мне нужно чтобы он указывал в точку, но точка постоянно меняет свое местоположение и мне нужно рассчитывать угол наклона вектора в реальном времени.

Comment: Так уже лучше. В каком виде вам нужно задавать углы наклона луча? Переформулирую. "Есть 2 точки (одна точка движется, а вторая - стоит на месте). Нужно найти углы наклона вектора в градусах из второй точки в первую?" Так, или я что-то еще упустил?

Comment: Все верно, по x диапазон значений от 0 до 360, по y от 0 до 180.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. получить нормализованный вектор между точками.
2. вычислить угол вектора в плоскости Y-Z (через арктангенс) - получится угол X
3. вычислить угол вектора в плоскости Z-XY - получится угол Y

Вот примерный код, который вы сможете адаптировать в C++:

```
function VectorToEuler(const A: TKMVertex3): TKMVertex2;
var
  Dist: Single;
begin
  Dist := Sqrt(Sqr(A.X) + Sqr(A.Y));

  // Переводим XY в угол X
  Result.X := ArcTan2(-A.X / Dist, A.Y / Dist) / Pi * 180;

  Dist := Sqrt(Sqr(A.X) + Sqr(A.Y) + Sqr(A.Z));

  // Переводим Z и XY в угол Y
  Result.Y := ArcTan2(A.Z / Dist, Sqrt(Sqr(A.X) + Sqr(A.Y)) / Dist) / Pi * 180;
end;
```

** *Код не оптимизирован, оставляю это вам.*